# How to backup and export all my pictures and data from Facebook?

Tags: facebook, backup, profile, profile-picture

Before, in Facebook I found a feature for backup my data. I sent that request and then Facebook sent me an email containing a link for downloading a file larger that 100 MB.

I want to back it up selective. And I want to download the archive in 5/20 MB split files.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to download either individual components of your Facebook profile - photos, messages, wall posts, updates, friends etc - or indeed the whole thing, then you should use SocialSafe. You can specify what parts of your account that you back up to your own machine and the user interface makes it easy to browse or search through it.

You can download it for free from the [SocialSafe](http://socialsafe.net) website.

It also supports Twitter, Instagram, Google+, LinkedIn and Viadeo. Worth checking out.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot split that file before having downloaded it. So you first need to download that 100MB file to your computer. Then you can split it.

Download 7zip: http://www.7-zip.org/

Then use the split file option to split. See the following tutorial:

http://www.newsgroupreviews.com/guides/7-zip-split-archive.html

Comment: before download i want to split that file. for example a site download that and archive in the internet by my permission.